# Create Table with multiple "WITH" Common table expression (CTE)

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, ddl, create-table

below is my oracle query- How do I modify the query to **create a  table** in my oracle database? I am using SQL Developer, please advise-

I want to create a table named "Team" with all the columns from the last select  query (column names: g,h,a,b,d,e)

```
WITH 
    Nam1 as (Select a,b from aaa),
    Nam2 as (select d,e from bbb)

Select  dd.g
       ,pp.h
       ,qq.a
       ,qq.b
       ,gg.d
       ,gg.e
from nam3 dd
join nam4 pp on dd.id = pp.id
join nam1 qq on pp.id = qq.id
join nam2 gg on qq.id = gg.id
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just prepend your query with a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE Team AS
WITH 
    Nam1 as (Select a,b from aaa),
    Nam2 as (Select d,e from bbb)

Select  dd.g
       ,pp.h
       ,qq.a
       ,qq.b
       ,gg.d
       ,gg.e
  from nam3 dd
  join nam4 pp on dd.id = pp.id
  join nam1 qq on pp.id = qq.id
  join nam2 gg on qq.id = gg.id;
```